# Adding a button in sales order. Old vs New Approach

Tags: event-observer, sales-order

Okay, I am a very new magento developer. Here is what I am facing.

- Module one -> is adding a button to sales order page by rewriting **sales_order_view**
- Module two -> is adding a button to sales order page by Observer (the new approach)

This ends up only showing Module one buttons.

How can this be fixed in a way where buttons from both modules show up ?

Module1-Buttons are being added via this pastebin.com/U8ujJpV5

Module2-Buttons are being added via this pastebin.com/j6VxwfF5 .

If I should post something more than this please let me know but I believe this would explain the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Some code may help us understand better

Comment: Module1-Buttons are being added via this http://pastebin.com/U8ujJpV5 Module2-Buttons are being added via this http://pastebin.com/j6VxwfF5 . If I should post something more than this please let me know but I believe this would explain the problem. Thank you

Comment: @sami1255 please check my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the buttons of both modules should show up. Ideas why this is not the case:

- Module one which rewrites the block removes the `dispatchEvent` call of the event used by the second module. I think this is rather unlikely, because most of the time a quite generic event is used in order to add the button.
- The modules add the buttons with the same `sortOrder`. If this is the case, Magento will only show one of the buttons. I published a fix for for that bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/sprankhub/Spranks_WidgetContainerButtonsFix).

Alright, now that you posted the code I could comprehend it. The reason why it does not work is that the code which uses the observer method checks the block class like that:

```
get_class($block) == 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
```

And only if that condition is true it will add the button. Since the other module rewrites the block and the block type is then `Aramex_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View`, this check will fail every time. What you can do:

1. Change the check to `$block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View` - this is the better way and it works with that check. If this is not your extension, consider writing the author and propose this change.
2. [not recommended] Change the check to `get_class($block) == 'Aramex_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View'`.
3. Change the `Aramex_Shipment` extension to also add the button via the event/observer method. If this is not your extension, consider writing the author and propose this change.